# D3 colors are not coming up as expected

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ynWB0GznvrMMRmqkaqaA?p=preview) as example

and I created [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VYH5QbO99ZbMkvc2D4Fe?p=preview) with same color scales

**Problem?**

I don't really understand how the following function works

```
var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
                .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

g.append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .style("fill", function(d) { 
        //console.log('d: ' + JSON.stringify(d, null, 4));
        return color(d.value); })
```

I am not sure how can I bring my pie charts to life by using colors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want specific colours, it will be easier to simply assign them instead of using a scale. Instead of using a custom scale, you might also want to use the [color scales D3 provides](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#wiki-category10).